# Python Hangs While Using cx_Oracle.execute()

Tags: python, execute, cx-oracle

I'm trying to perform a `cx_Oracle.execute(sql_string, sql_data_dict)` command.

`sql_string` is my SQL query and it's something like `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(VAR1, VAR2) VALUES (:var1_, :var2_)` and `sql_data_dict` is a dictionary containing variable defined in the query; something like this:

`{var1_: "my_first_variable", var2_: "my_second_variable"}`.

Python hangs on the command `cx_Oracle.execute(sql_string, sql_data_dict)`. As I checked to debug inside the code, it appears that it doesn't go to the library to perform `execute` and I don't know why.

I also tried to use `cursor.prepare` as following:

```
cursor.prepare(sql_string)
cursor.execute(None, sql_data_dict)
```

But I had same result. Any help?

**EDIT 1:**

I should mention that I execute my query using Navicat and I have no problem. Additionally, there is no bug about `SELECT` statement, so it's just about `INSERT` already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled for a couple of hours and then I realized it was just a server-side problem; since the server was overloaded, it had rejected some queries. So I should just say that there is nothing wrong with the code, it may occur when server's load gets huge.

Comment: How did you know that the server is overloaded, I'm having the same problem but I am not sure if it's the same case.

Comment: @arsenbonbon, I have used this script to know how many parallel connections have been made to the database: `select * from v$session where schemaname='SCHEMA_NAME'; `.